# Is ARIMAX suitable for time series with exogenous variables?

Tags: arima

I have the following data:

```
Date          Fruit    Color    y
01/01/2018    apples   red      0.435
02/01/2018    oranges  green    0.234
...
01/01/2019    bananas  purple   0.234
```

I want to predict y for future dates. I have used linear and logistic regression but never worked with dates. So I have three "regressors": date, fruit and color. I have read about ARIMAX, but I don't quite understand if this is the technique suitable for this problem. I have also read about seasonality, but I am no expert in this topic, so how can I tell if my data has seasonality?

Comment: You would need to read at least one book or take at least one course on time series analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Foe each fruit and color combination SEPARETLY you want to form a predictive model. Apparently you have no predictor/exogenous series thus ARMAX Becomes ARMA . Simply follow the paradigm presented here https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf and you will be good to go . If the software you select assumes 1) no deterministic structure OR constant parameters over time OR constant error variance over time be VERY wary !

If you have seasonality (which is to  be expected for fruits) the data will tell you that via analytics.

Comment: Why fruits and color can't be predictors?